# .map no es una funcion en un array con objetos

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, electron

en la aplicacion, se require que el usuario suba imagenes y al mismo tiempo le muestro una `preview` de la carta que se va a subir, pero al agregar un objeto al array con imagenes este me devuelve que .map no es na funcion, no entiendo por que, les dejo mi codigo

```
const [nombre, setNombre] = React.useState("");
const [seccion, setSeccion] = React.useState("");
const [precio, setPrecio] = React.useState("");
const [descripcion, setDescripcion] = React.useState("");
const [imagenes, setImagenes] = React.useState([]);
const [preview, setPreview] = React.useState([]);
const [marca, setMarca] = React.useState("");
const [cantidad, setCantidad] = React.useState("");
const [ i, setI ] = React.useState(false)

const settings = {
  dots: true,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 500,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  autoplay: false
};

const handleChangeNombre = event => {
  const { value } = event.target;
  setNombre(value);
};
const handleChangeSeccion = event => {
  const { value } = event.target;
  setSeccion(value);
};
const handleChangePrecio = event => {
  const { value } = event.target;
  setPrecio(value);
};
const handleChangeDescripcion = event => {
  const { value } = event.target;
  setDescripcion(value);
};
const uploadFile = event => {
  const { files } = event.target;
  for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    const load = new FileReader()
    load.readAsDataURL(files[i])
    load.onload = res => {
      const { result } = res.target
      const obj = {
        url: result,
        data: files[i] 
      }
      setPreview(preview.push(obj))
      setI(true)
    }
  }
};
const handleChangeMarca = event => {
  const { value } = event.target;
  setMarca(value);
};
const handleChangeCantidad = event => {
  const { value } = event.target;
  setCantidad(value);
};

const submit = event => {
  event.preventDefault();

  Post("createArticle", { imagenes })
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err.response)
    });
};

const classes = useStyles()
return (
  <div className={classes.dea}>
    <form
    onSubmit={submit}
    className={classes.roott}
    autoComplete="off"
    encType="multipart/form-data"
  >
    <TextField
      label="Titulo"
      type="text"
      value={nombre}
      onChange={handleChangeNombre}
      className={classes.input}
      required
    />
    <TextField
      label="Seccion"
      type="text"
      value={seccion}
      onChange={handleChangeSeccion}
      className={classes.input}
      required
    />
    <TextField
      label="Marca"
      type="text"
      value={marca}
      onChange={handleChangeMarca}
      className={classes.input}
      required
    />
    <TextField
      label="Precio"
      value={precio}
      onChange={handleChangePrecio}
      InputProps={{
        inputComponent: NumberFormatCustom,
      }}
      className={classes.input}
      required
    />
    <TextField
      label="Descripcion"
      type="text"
      value={descripcion}
      onChange={handleChangeDescripcion}
      className={classes.input}
      required
    />
    <TextField
      label="Cantidad"
      type="text"
      value={cantidad}
      onChange={handleChangeCantidad}
      className={classes.input}
      required
    />
    <input
      type="file"
      style={{ display: 'none' }}
      id="image"
      accept="image/*"
      name="imagen"
      multiple={true}
      onChange={uploadFile}
    />
    <label htmlFor="image" className={classes.upload}>
      <Button
        component="span"
        variant="contained"
        color="default"
        className={classes.button}
        startIcon={<CloudUploadIcon />}
      >
        Subir imagen
      </Button>
    </label>
    <Button type="submit" variant="contained" color="primary">
      Publicar
    </Button>
  </form>
  <div className={classes.previewImages}>
    <Typography className={classes.textHeaderImagePreview}>
      Vista previa de la carta
    </Typography>
    <div>
      <Card className={classes.root}>
        <CardActionArea>
          <div className={classes.section}>
            <div className={classes.container}>
              <GridContainer>
                <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={12} className={classes.marginAuto}>
                  <Cards carousel style={{ margin: 0 }}>
                    <Carousel {...settings} >
                        {i ?
                        preview.map((item, i) => (
                          <div key={i}>
                            <img
                              src={item.url}
                              alt="imagen de demostracion"
                              className="slick-image"
                            />
                          </div>
                        ))
                      :
                      null}
                    </Carousel>
                  </Cards>
                </GridItem>
              </GridContainer>
            </div>
          </div>
          <CardContent>
            <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
              {nombre}
            </Typography>
            <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
              {descripcion}
            </Typography>
          </CardContent>
        </CardActionArea>
        <CardActions>
          <Button size="small" color="primary">
            Ver
          </Button>
          <Button size="small" color="primary">
            Ver mas tarde
          </Button>
          <Button size="small" color="secondary">
            {precio ?
              `$ ${precio}`
              :
              null
            }
          </Button>
        </CardActions>
      </Card>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
)
}
```

por si no quedo claro el problema, lo redacto mas detallado a contiuacion,
//esta aplicacion esta echa con electron y react, esta aplicacion valga la redundancia, es para poder agegar productos en una pagina web que ya esta armada, la carta que nombro, es una demostracion de como va a quedar en la web, lo que quiero hacer aca, es que el usuario agrege imagenes del producto, y crear un Fileread para poder previsualizarla, no se si el problema sera que estoy agregando mal el `obj` al estado, la verdad no se cual sera el problema, pero a la hora de subir la imagen la consola me devuelve que `preview.map` no es una funcion, si no me explico bien seguire dando mas detalles.

Comment: Estás mutando preview directamente? `preview.push(obj)` ? Setea el resultado de meter el nuevo item en una nueva lista.

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez sea debido a la línea:

```
setPreview(preview.push(obj));
```

Intenta de la forma:

```
setPreview(prevState => ([...prevState, obj]));
```

Comment: me resulto, ahora supongamos que quiero sacar cierto objeto, como deberai de hacer, me puedes explicar?

Comment: @Enzo dado que estamos hablando que preview es un array, necesitas usar el método filter. https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter